# VMWare Fusion - Accessing IIS on Windows 10 Guest OS from Chrome on OSX Host OS

Tags: macos, iis, windows-authentication, vmware-fusion

I have a Windows 10 VM installed on VMWare Fusion 8 on my MacBook pro. I have installed IIS and set up an application configured to use Windows authentication.

When I try to log in from a browser on the Windows 10 VM, it works with no issues. However, when I try to log in from the host MacOS X, it repeatedly prompts for credentials.

I have tried the following:

1. Gave the VM a static IP address (https://willwarren.com/2015/04/02/set-static-ip-address-in-vmware-fusion-7/) and mapped the IP to the VM's hostname in the OSX hosts file
2. Disabled anonymous authentication, and set IIS to allow Windows Authentication only
3. Removed 'Negotiate' provider for Windows Authentication, leaving only NTLM
4. Set application pool to use 'NetworkService' as identity
5. Provided 'NETWORk SERVICE' user with full control permissions over website's directory